# How can I store and retrieve objects from Google Apps Script Project Properties?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to store objects in google apps script properties.

Lets say I have an object: `var myObject = {var1:"stuffval", var2:"stuff2val"};`

If I store this as a property via `scriptProperties.setProperty("myProperty", myObject );` the property is stored as a string that is `{var1=stuffval, var2=stuff2val}`.

How can I retrieve my object from that string within Google Apps Script?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Convert the object to a string before putting it into Properties Service.  All of the Properties Services store the data as a string.  Properties Service will automatically convert non-strings to strings before storing the data, but with an object you should use the `JSON` service to correctly convert the object to a string.  Then convert the object as a string back to a real object with `JSON.parse(theObject)`

```
var myObject = {var1:"stuffval", var2:"stuff2val"};//Example - object literal

PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()
  .setProperty("myProperty", JSON.stringify(myObject) );//stringify the object
```

Convert back to an object:

```
var returnedObj = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties("myProperty");
returnedObj = JSON.parse(returnedObj);
```

Don't use `scriptProperties` it's deprecated.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give that a shot. For clarification, I am not using the depreciated `ScriptProperties` class. I am using the `PropertiesService` class which exposes a `getScriptProperties()` method. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service