# Where should I be calling the getUserProperties function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, google-apps-script

I'm trying to create a button that, upon clicking, "saves" the positions of multiple lists from a connected-sortable. I want the script to be able to retain the most recent position of each list item when the page is refreshed (*i.e. If list 1 starts as A,B,C and I change it to B,A,C and refresh the page, it stays as B,A,C.*).

I'm attempting to accomplish this by creating an array from an html document (published as a web app), save it using the `getUserProperities` function, and then return it the next time I open the web app.

I am able to log the positions without issue, but I'm having trouble figuring out where to run the `getUserProperities` function, or what other issue I may be dealing with.

In the console from the web app, I get this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getUserProperties' of undefined at saveList (userCodeAppPanel:4) at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (userCodeAppPanel:1)`.

Where should I be calling the `getUserProperties` function? From `code.gs` or `index.html`? I have been working off the example provided [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34302070/how-can-i-store-and-retrieve-objects-from-google-apps-script-project-properties).

The relevant portions of my code, from `index.html` are below.

```
<script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#myList, #flight1a, #flight1b, #flight2a, #flight2b, #flight3a, #flight3b, #sortable2" ).sortable({
      connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
      update: function(event, ui) {
        var changedList = this.id;
        var order = $(this).sortable('toArray');
        var positions = order.join(';');

        console.log({
        id: changedList,
        positions: positions

        });
      }
    })
   });

</script>

 <script>
    function saveList() {

      google.script.run.PropertiesService.getUserProperties().setProperty('myProperty', JSON.stringify(positions));

      var returnedObj = PropertiesService.getUserProperties("myProperty");
          returnedObj = JSON.parse(returnedObj);
      }  
</script>

  </head>

  <body>

<button onclick="saveList()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Apps Script natives such as `PropertiesService` are only available within the context of the Apps Script server environment. You'll need to create a server side function `foo(...)` that you call from the client code. In your server functions, you would set / get the relevant items.

Comment: Do not forget to review the Apps Script guides on client server communication - they will be very helpful.

Comment: I did go through the guide, which is why I assumed I needed to call it from the client side and used google.script.run, but I wasn't really sure how to get the two sides to communicate and share data back and forth. I wasn't sure what the server side function would need to return for the PropertiesService to actually run, so I tried to do it directly from the client side. That clarifies it some.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Properties Service can only be accessed through Google Apps Script, so it must be called in one of your `*.gs` files. To execute a server-side function, you need to use [`google.script.run`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run) (there's also a [guide available](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)).

For example, in your `code.gs` file add this function:

```
function savePositions(propertyName, value) {
  PropertiesService.getUserProperties().setProperty(propertyName, value);
}
```

Then, in your `index.html` file modify `saveList()` to:

```
function saveList() {
  google.script.run.savePositions("myProperty", JSON.stringify(positions));
}
```

Comment: I did know about the guide which is why I used google.script.run, but I didn't know what the server side function would need to return ( wasn't sure how to get 
`positions` from the client side to server side) for the PropertiesService to actually run, so I tried to do it directly from the client side. I'll try this tomorrow (midnight for me now and I need to be up for work in 6 hours. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @NateDavis The server side function doesn't _need_ to return anything, but you can do so using the various `withFailureHandler(function)`/`withSuccessHandler(function)`/`withUserObject(object)` methods.

Comment: I applied the function as you suggested but I'm still not getting the result I'm looking for. Would it be best to start a new thread? I have gotten this error in the console: "Uncaught ReferenceError: positions is not defined at saveList (userCodeAppPanel:3)at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (userCodeAppPanel:1)."

Comment: And when I change where I place the `saveList` function in index.html, I still get an error: Uncaught ReferenceError: saveList is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (userCodeAppPanel:1)

Comment: @NateDavis Yes, this is a separate problem related to your jQuery. The function you have that defines `position` doesn't talk with `saveList()`, so you're not saving anything.

Answer (score 3):

`google.script.run` could be used to call a server side function not to call directly the Properties Service.

For further details see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run

Comment: Ok that's helpful to know (and easy to understand!). I did go through the guide but for someone relatively new to this it might as well have been in another language.