# Send an array from the client-side to the server-side and return it to the client-side with PropertiesService

Tags: google-apps-script

I want the script to be able to retain the most recent position of each list item when the page is refreshed (i.e. If list 1 starts as A,B,C and I change it to B,A,C and refresh the page, it stays as B,A,C.).

I'm attempting to use the `PropertiesService` to take an array from the web app, save it and then return it to the web app so that when I refresh the page, all the list items are in their most recent position.

You can see the previous question I am working from [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51510370/where-should-i-be-calling-the-getuserproperties-function/51510579). (I started a new thread because this is related, but is a separate issue.) Going off of that and the comments/answered provided there, what I have below is not working as intended. One error I've gotten from the console is `Uncaught ReferenceError: saveList is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick`.

**How do I get the `PropertiesService` to save the list AND return it when I refresh the page?**

**How do I get the client and server sides to "communicate" with each other?**

As Diego pointed out, *"The function you have that defines position doesn't talk with `saveList()`, so you're not saving anything."* I'm just not sure how to make that happen.

**How do I get the `positions` array from index.html, to code.gs and back to index.html?**

FROM CODE.GS:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
}

function savePositions(myProperty, positions) {
 PropertiesService.getUserProperties().setProperty("myProperty", positions);
}
```

FROM INDEX.HTML:

```
<script>
      $(function() {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(buildOptionsList)
            .getTeamArray();    
      });


      function buildOptionsList(uniqueArray) {
        var div = document.getElementById('myList');
          for (var i = 0; i < uniqueArray.length; i++) {
            var ul = document.createElement('ul');
            var li = document.createElement('li');
            var cLass = li.setAttribute('class','ui-state-default');
            var iD = li.setAttribute('id',uniqueArray[i]);


        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(uniqueArray[i]));
        div.appendChild(ul);
        div.appendChild(li);
          }
       }
</script>

<script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#myList, #flight1a, #flight1b, #flight2a, #flight2b, #flight3a, #flight3b, #sortable2" ).sortable({
      connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
      update: function(event, ui) {
        var changedList = this.id;
        var order = $(this).sortable('toArray');
        var positions = order.join(';');

        console.log({
        id: changedList,
        positions: positions

        });
         function saveList() {
  google.script.run.savePositions("myProperty", JSON.stringify(positions));

  JSON.parse("myProperty");
} 
}
    })
   });

</script>

  </head>

  <body>

    <button onclick="saveList()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Can you write a function in your jQuery called `getPositions()` that returns just the positions?

Comment: by separating the function that gets the positions and the one to make the sortable work, I get this `Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on sortable prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'toArray'`

Comment: It's not a question of "can you". You **need** to make a function get position that gets the property and only **then** parses them

Comment: Ok thanks. That gives me something to tinker with when I get back from work.